How to use script in opensearch to query documents based on a specific value at a given index in an array?
I want to query some documents from elastic based on the first element in an array stored in a particular field in the document. But not getting the desired output.
{
                "script": {
                  "script": {
                    "source": "if (doc.containsKey('n0') && doc['n0'].size() > 1 && doc['n0'][0]==2) { return true} else { return false; }",
                    "lang": "painless"
                  }
                }
              }

This is the query which im running. The value at 'n0' can be single number or an array of numbers. I want to query the documents in which the first element in 'n0' array is 2. But I'm getting results with 'n0' values [2,1], [1,2], [3,2] etc.
{
          "record_decimal_field": {
            "match": """^n\d+$""",
            "match_mapping_type": "double",
            "match_pattern": "regex",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "float"
            }
          }
        }

This is the mapping of 'n0' field. Any idea what I'm doing wrong in here?

I tested it on both elasticsearch and opensearch and I don't get results that you describe. I only get results for [3,2] as I would expect. It happens because you are retrieving data from doc values and doc value don't preserve the order of values, so both [1,2] and [2,1] will be returned to you as [1,2]. If positional information is important you should index values in these positions in separate fields.
